# jqueryui slider global settings

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

In jquery ui 1.7.* I used to do :

```
 $.extend($.ui.slider.defaults,{object with defaults});
```

In 1.8 it doesn't work.

What's the standard way of setting defaults in 1.8 ?

Comment: what is inside the object you are extending?

Comment: well in $.ui.slider.defaults used to be the default settings  that I would override. And it would use these settings for all instances of sidebar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via the [jQuery UI 1.8 upgrade guide](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Upgrade_Guide), `$.ui.foo.defaults` was moved to `$.ui.foo.prototype.options`.

So for your example, you would set the defaults for all slider instances by:

```
$.extend($.ui.slider.prototype.options, { object with defaults });
```

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287045/override-jqueryui-dialog-default-options