# JQuery UI Dialogs: application-wide options

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I have swarm of jquery-ui dialogs across my app. Every single time I need a new one, I write the following lines:

```
$('.another-dialog').dialog({
  title: 'Another dialog',
  autoOpen: false,
  draggable: true,
  modal: true,
  show: 'fade',
  hide: 'fade',
  width: 400,
  position: ['center', 'center'],
  buttons: [
    { text: 'Ok' },
    { text: 'Cancel' }
  ],
  open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close span").html('×') }
});
```

The only things that are really differ between one dialog from another are the `buttons` and `title` keys. What I would like to have here is an application-wide setup for JQuery dialog, so the I would only call

```
$('.another-dialog').dialog({
  title: 'Another dialog',
  buttons: [
    { text: 'Ok' },
    { text: 'Cancel' }
  ]
});
```

with all the needed hash keys implicitly set up (i'd call it — "the default" setup).

I know I can wrap `.dialog()` call in, say, `.myDialog()` call where I'd set everything by myself. But I wonder if there's a true, convenient way of doing that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287045/override-jqueryui-dialog-default-options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the common options in a variable (or in the [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) associated with the document if you want to use them from different scopes):

```
$(document).data("common-dialog-options", {
    autoOpen: false,
    draggable: true,
    modal: true,
    show: "fade",
    hide: "fade",
    width: 400,
    position: ["center", "center"],
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close span").html("×");
    }
});
```

You can then use [$.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) to add the specific options for each dialog:

```
$(".another-dialog").dialog(
    $.extend({}, $(document).data("common-dialog-options"), {
        title: "Another dialog",
        buttons: [
            { text: "OK" },
            { text: "Cancel" }
        ]
    })
);
```

Comment: Nice one. But why store it in the document's data. Why not just a global (or local to the main scope) variable?

Comment: @Joseph, I personally prefer `data()` to global variables (mostly for namespace pollution reasons), and I cannot guarantee the questioner only has one "main" scope, so... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var defaultDialog = {
  title: 'Another dialog',
  autoOpen: false,
  draggable: true,
  modal: true,
  show: 'fade',
  hide: 'fade',
  width: 400,
  position: ['center', 'center'],
  buttons: [
    { text: 'Ok' },
    { text: 'Cancel' }
  ],
  open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close span").html('×') }
};

var tunnedDialog= jQuery.extend(true, {}, defaultDialog );

tunnedDialog.title: 'Another dialog';
tunnedDialog.buttons: [
    { text: 'Ok' },
    { text: 'Cancel' }
  ]

$('.another-dialog').dialog(tunnedDialog);
```